# AlarmManager alert after defined time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

**Below is my code**

```
public static void startAlarmManager(Context context, Date date) {

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);

    PendingIntent recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), NOTIFY_ME_ID,
            alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.cancel(recurringAlarm);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarms.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), recurringAlarm);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        alarms.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), recurringAlarm);
    } else {
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), recurringAlarm);
    }

}
```

This code works correctly in all device on which I have tested. But I am facing issue with **Wiko Jerry mt6580**.

In this device alarm is triggered after **five** minutes, of the intended time.

> Note: The tests made with the devices connected to charger, to not
>   active o doze mode.

Any suggestions why I am getting this problem, or how to solve it would be of great help.

-Thanks!